# Scraping and capturing multi-tile product info with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Website I am scraping data from: https://www.nike.com/w/sale-3yaep ..

I am currently extracting the URL of each product displayed on the page. My issue is for the products with multiple tiles (i.e. multiple colors), I am not able to get info for those other colors. For example, if you find a product with multiple colors and inspect the html of the product -- you can hover over the image and see the URL change as you hover over different colors.

So the problem is the HTML will only contain details of product URL's of the default products. Is there any workaround for getting the data from products with multiple colors?

Code below:

```
pages = 'https://www.nike.com/w/sale-3yaep'
page = requests.get(pages,verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for prod in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'product-card__body'}):
   prod_tag = prod.find('a')
   link = str(prod_tag['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is stored iside `<script>` tag so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `re`/`json` modules to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.nike.com/w/sale-3yaep"

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"window\.INITIAL_REDUX_STATE=(\{.*\})", html_doc)
data = json.loads(data.group(1))

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for p in data["Wall"]["products"]:
    print(p["title"], p["subtitle"])
    colors = p.get("colorways") or []
    for c in colors:
        print(
            "{:<50} {}".format(
                c["colorDescription"],
                c["pdpUrl"].format(countryLang="https://www.nike.com"),
            )
        )
    print()
```

Prints:

```
Nike Air Max Command Men's Shoe
Black/Neutral Grey/Anthracite                      https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-command-shoe-bdw7RQ/749760-001

Nike WearAllDay Older Kids' Shoe
Black/Black/Black                                  https://www.nike.com/t/wearallday-older-shoe-xtvQKM/CJ3816-001
Smoke Grey/Pink Glow/Off-Noir/Metallic Copper      https://www.nike.com/t/wearallday-older-shoe-xtvQKM/CJ3816-006
White/Black                                        https://www.nike.com/t/wearallday-older-shoe-xtvQKM/CJ3816-101

Nike Downshifter 10 Men's Running Shoe
Black/Iron Grey/Black                              https://www.nike.com/t/downshifter-10-running-shoe-QL0NBl/CI9981-002

Nike ESC Men's Knit Tracksuit Jacket
Black                                              https://www.nike.com/t/esc-knit-tracksuit-jacket-sHVQ8Q/CW3744-010

None None

Nike Downshifter 11 Women's Running Shoe
White/Pure Platinum/Wolf Grey/Metallic Silver      https://www.nike.com/t/downshifter-11-running-shoe-lp6Sh5/CW3413-100

Nike Swoosh Run Women's Mid-Rise 7/8 Running Leggings
Black                                              https://www.nike.com/t/swoosh-run-mid-rise-7-8-running-leggings-6vw38F/DA1145-010

Nike Air Max Zephyr Older Kids' Shoe
Black/Dark Smoke Grey                              https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zephyr-older-shoe-GmwbKV/CN8511-001
Smoke Grey/Black/Photon Dust/Siren Red             https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zephyr-older-shoe-GmwbKV/CN8511-003
Black/Sapphire/Sunset Pulse/Metallic Silver        https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zephyr-older-shoe-GmwbKV/CN8511-004

Nike Air Zoom Pulse Shoes
Black/Black/Black                                  https://www.nike.com/t/air-zoom-pulse-shoes-9PlRZ2/CT1629-003

Nike Sportswear Down-Fill Windrunner Men's Jacket
Black/Black/Black/Black                            https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-down-fill-windrunner-jacket-hHNjxL/CU4404-010
White/Dark Smoke Grey/Dark Smoke Grey/Black        https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-down-fill-windrunner-jacket-hHNjxL/CU4404-100

Nike Air Max 2090 Women's Shoe
Black/Metallic Silver/White                        https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-2090-shoe-C0FP38/CK2612-002
White/Wolf Grey/Black                              https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-2090-shoe-C0FP38/CK2612-100

Nike One Women's Mid-Rise Crop Graphic Leggings
Black/Light Photo Blue/Chile Red                   https://www.nike.com/t/one-mid-rise-crop-graphic-leggings-LNLjt9/CZ9202-011

Nike Reposto Older Kids' Shoe
Black/Dark Smoke Grey/Iron Grey/White              https://www.nike.com/t/reposto-older-shoe-CMDjSc/DA3260-012
Grey Fog/Iron Grey/Volt/Game Royal                 https://www.nike.com/t/reposto-older-shoe-CMDjSc/DA3260-005
Light Violet/Crimson Bliss/Platinum Tint/Metallic Silver https://www.nike.com/t/reposto-older-shoe-CMDjSc/DA3260-500

Nike City Trainer 3 Women's Training Shoes
Black/Anthracite/White                             https://www.nike.com/t/city-trainer-3-training-shoes-lChhbP/CK2585-006

Nike Air Zoom Winflo 7 Men's Running Shoe
Black/Anthracite/White                             https://www.nike.com/t/air-zoom-wio-7-running-shoe-BsFScT/CJ0291-005

Nike ESC Men's Modern Polo
Navy                                               https://www.nike.com/t/esc-modern-polo-0skhPC/CW3747-414
Black                                              https://www.nike.com/t/esc-modern-polo-0skhPC/CW3747-010

Nike Air Max 2X Women's Shoe
White/White/Black                                  https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-2x-shoe-3hqsQl/CK2947-100
Black/Black/White                                  https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-2x-shoe-3hqsQl/CK2947-001

Nike Sportswear Swoosh Women's Woven Trousers
Steam                                              https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-swoosh-woven-trousers-N3gKw3/CZ8909-006
University Gold                                    https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-swoosh-woven-trousers-N3gKw3/CZ8909-739

Nike MD Runner 2 Men's Shoe
Midnight Navy/Wolf Grey/White                      https://www.nike.com/t/md-runner-2-shoes-PATZpBgm/749794-410
Black/Anthracite/White                             https://www.nike.com/t/md-runner-2-shoes-PATZpBgm/749794-010

Nike Sportswear Essential Women's Dress
Black/White                                        https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-essential-dress-kdTcH3/CU6509-010

Nike Air Max ZM950 Older Kids' Shoe
Black/Volt/Smoke Grey/White                        https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zm950-older-shoe-fhbCg2/CN9835-003
Light Bone/Stone/Sequoia/Citron Pulse              https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zm950-older-shoe-fhbCg2/CN9835-005
Black/Metallic Silver/Bright Crimson/Black         https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zm950-older-shoe-fhbCg2/CN9835-002
Black/Sapphire/White/Sunset Pulse                  https://www.nike.com/t/air-max-zm950-older-shoe-fhbCg2/CN9835-006

Nike Sportswear Older Kids' (Girls') Crop T-Shirt
Pink Foam/White                                    https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-older-crop-t-shirt-MM4cdd/DJ4017-663

Nike SB Zoom Blazer Low Pro GT Skate Shoe
Black/Black/Gum Light Brown/White                  https://www.nike.com/t/sb-zoom-blazer-low-pro-gt-skate-shoe-bMwZmc/DC7695-002

Nike Sportswear Synthetic-Fill Men's Jacket
Black/Black/Black/Sail                             https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-synthetic-fill-jacket-63lvqV/CU4422-010
Midnight Navy/Midnight Navy/Midnight Navy/Sail     https://www.nike.com/t/sportswear-synthetic-fill-jacket-63lvqV/CU4422-410

Nike SuperRep Groove Women's Cardio Dance Shoes
White/Metallic Gold Coin/Black/Black               https://www.nike.com/t/superrep-groove-cardio-dance-shoes-b9WmfB/CT1248-109
White/Chutney/Black                                https://www.nike.com/t/superrep-groove-cardio-dance-shoes-b9WmfB/CT1248-107
```

Comment: Thanks! Question -- one thing I've noticed with INITIAL_REDUX_STATE is that it will only capture data on the first/default page of the website. I've tried using Selenium to dynamically scroll down the website and capture the INITIAL_REDUX_STATE data, but the result is the same -- the INITIAL_REDUX_STATE doesn't update or reload with new data. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @dmd7 I don't have much experience with `selenium`, but looking into the Developer Tools/Network Tab - when you scroll down there are requests to `https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v1?...` which returns new data. You can probably simulate these calls with `requests` module.

Comment: Do you know if the INITIAL_REDUX_STATE is supposed to update as you scroll down the page? @Andrej Kesely